# Update easyphp-devserver from v14 to v16

Tags: easyphp

I have EasyPHP devserver v14.1 and I want to upgrade to v16.1.1, how can I do that? Just run the v16 installer over the v14? I mean, I don't want to lose my configuration and websites in my computer. Is that possible? or I have to remove v14 and reinstall and recreate everything?
I have installed some modules, MySQL PhpMyAdmin 4.3.4 and Virtual host manager 1.4.